# Can we play only audio using youtube api for iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, youtube

In my project i have to use youtube api and play only audio of the video. We must not show the youtube player. Is it possible to play only audio without showing video using youtube api?

Comment: Try not to build the next Spotify with YouTube as your source! Extracting audio is against YouTube's TOS. With this idea, you are risking access termination to their API if not a letter in the mail from their legal team if you pull it off big.

Comment: @ThinkCode who said anything about "Spotify" and music? There are ton of great open course ware and I do not really understand why so many apps can get away with audio/video download options and why Google/YouTube is not open, If a particular video is accessible publicly then why not just the audio? The OP might appreciate the insight.

Comment: @ablaze It is simple really. YouTube provides all the content for free with some ads. When you bypass the viewing portion of the video by simply extracting audio, there is no revenue generated for that content-grab. Revenue powers the free services. Server resources that help host and deliver content are not free and will not be free just like the food we eat. You can get away with using adblock and a custom project for yourself and your family but making it an app for everyone to use won't fly, at least with not Google's lawyers!

Comment: Thanks! I am not a 'YouTuber' per se, but I notice that not all videos have promotions? e.g. https://youtu.be/FGugpmN_S8w?list=PL3FBB913A985D7F31. Also, does not YouTube API has a way to query if the video has promotions? If not what you said above might not be applicable. So I am not sure how YouTube would justify that.

Comment: And downloading would absolutely decrease the coast for data transmission for YouTube, but I'd opine that if Google does not prefer it then streaming just the audio would also save them bandwidth. ( with airing commercials like radio and to your own example, Spotify, too  does )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Extraction may be the incorrect implied word here. From what I understand, is user133611 wants to have an audio only stream from YouTube.  Unfortunately, YouTube directly forbids it. Here is a quote from Kuan Yong from the YouTube API team:

> Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create
> functionality for Your users or other third parties to:
>
> > "separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any  YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API"
>
> -Kuan Yong, YouTube API Team

Link reference: https://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/7fac8e8ff913b6c4?pli=1

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is really possible only using Youtube API. The Youtube API is not intended to be used for "downloading" videos/audio from them. You should go [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html), to understand what the Youtube API is really about.

**A small abstract:**

Unless I am missing something really big, the Youtube API consists of 5 main parts:

[Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api)
[Custom Player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#custom_player)
[YouTube Direct](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/ytdirect.html)
[Player APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis)
[Widgets](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#widgets)

None of this APIs allow you to for example "download" a video. Also I think (correct me if I'm wrong), that in a youtube video, the audio is actually embedded in the flash video, making the task even less trivial.

To illustrate you, the Data API, allows you to perform and use the youtube video search capabilities, use playlist capabilities and many more of the operations available on the YouTube website.

That have being said, the Youtube API, can be used for example to upload a video from your iPhone to youtube, as [this](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-iphone/) example illustrates.

**My Thoughts:**

I think that extracting the audio from a youtube video, is actually possible, but involves a whole different process of downloading the video in H264 and then extracting the audio... but it still involves downloading the whole video.

Answer (score 4):

Is the audio only prohibition still valid? Streamus is available as a Chrome Extension. It streams audio only from YT - see website https://streamus.com/

Comment: my thoughts exactly! also is streamus really downloading the video, then extracting the audio!! It seems to fast to be doing that! :/

Answer (score 3):

Well, one can simply give the video a width and height of `1px`, or better yet do:

```
.video { text-indent: -9999px; }
```

And then force the video to play via the API controls. But I wouldn't do it as it is against their TOS and would result in my app being blocked if they find out.

Comment: @d-_-b yea I suggested hiding it off screen in case YouTube has a way to detect display none for misuse similar to how search engines  used to detect black hat SEO tactics like hiding keywords in the same color as the background. Then again if they can detect display none I'm sure detecting off screen isn't beyond their technological reach :P

Comment: You are still technically streaming the video and using bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I really confused about your platform. Do you want to do it over iOS platform with writing native code? If yes, you can do it without playing video. But you have to stream both video and music. You can do it with AVAudioPlayer Class, check the reference from

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/

But yes, you will makes users GSM data overload and it's not fair with letting users about that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can force your view over the youtube view? Have you tried that?

Comment: This is not at all what this user is asking, ( unless he mis-explained himself really bad )

Comment: He states that "We must not show the youtube player.". That can also be achieved by forcing another view over the player, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

If it is against TOS, the op should just drop the idea of implementing his idea.

Just imagine the free music everyone will be streaming out of the promo videos of major videos on youtube!