# How can I only play sound using the Youtube Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

First of all, am I allowed to do this? If I put the Youtube player in an invisible container and have Javascript controls, will Youtube allow it?

If it is allowed, what's a good way to only play audio? (to save bandwidth for users who only want to listen to the audio)

Comment: That [seems to be disallowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312179/can-we-play-only-audio-using-youtube-api-for-iphone) by the API.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Setting display of an HTML Element containing an embed or an iframe will likely remove the flash from the page. However, you can always set the position to absolute and set left to something like -9999px.

Comment: "visibility:none" does the trick. It's easy to hide it. The question is, does Youtube allow it?

Comment: I have the same question but this is not the solution for me because the user has to download audio and video both to listen to audio only which will definitely cost him/her "extra" requests.Can anyone come with a solution? OR does google provides this facility in the first place?

Comment: @Linksku No, it is **not** allowed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed.

In the [YouTube API terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms), prohibitions 8 and 9 are that you cannot:

- separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API
- promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API