# is it possible to play audio instead of video from Youtube video link?

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube, mpmovieplayer

My requirement is something like this.I have 1 youtube video url and i have to play audio of that particular URL instead of Video so is it possible in iPhone/iPad to play this kind of audio from video link?Please guide me.

Comment: No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312179/can-we-play-only-audio-using-youtube-api-for-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are allowed to by Youtubes terms of use; I am referring to the API terms. However, it is certainly technically possible. One hackie but simple solution would be to make an invisible view that plays the video; you would never see the video but you should be able to here the audio; just set the view's alpha low.

However, I do not recommend breaking the terms for the API, as I am sure there would be repercussions. Best of luck with your client.