# Can I get youtube video as mp3 sound in iOS ?

Tags: ios, api, youtube, mp3

as mentioned in the question
Can I get the youtube as sound file with any extension 
I mean specifically with using JSON or any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get songs from Youtube is to use their API, and search for your song. It will return a youtubeID url of video/song.

You can then stream this into an iOS app.

A handy framework to extract video url from youtube ID url, is LBYoutubePlayer which can be found here https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

You would then need to extract the audio from the video.

Technically, that could all work. Not sure if it goes beyond Youtube's terms and services though.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. I thought there is something provided by youtube API .. I found this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312179/can-we-play-only-audio-using-youtube-api-for-iphone