# Load Youtube URL & Playing Only The Audio Of A Video File

Tags: ios, youtube, avaudioplayer, mpmovieplayer

I was wondering if there was any way to load a YouTube URL like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbJtYqBYCV8 and then only playing only the audio from this video in Xcode.

Thanks!

-Petahwil

Comment: try this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312179/can-we-play-only-audio-using-youtube-api-for-iphone