# Can audio data from an <iframe>, such as a YouTube video or embedded music player, be accessed with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, html5-audio, audio-player

I am embedding various players on my webpage (YouTube, Spotify, Bandcamp etc.) and would like to change my webpage's state based on the embedded  sound. How can this data be accessed?

UPDATE:
From [evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox) 's comment, I looked into the element of one of the Bandcamp embedded players, and found the below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var playerdata = {"tracks":[{"title":"Virga I","encodings_id":1606233426,"file":{"mp3-128":"https://t4.bcbits.com/stream/.....
        var parentpage = "http://localhost:8080/"; // page we are embedded in
        var params = {"tracklist":"false","fgcol":null,"url_referrer":false...

        $(function() {
            HTMLEmbeddedPlayer3.init(playerdata, parentpage, params);
        });
    </script>
```

This is cool, because I may be able to see this iframe's "playerdata" var programmatically, and access the audio when the user clicks play? I'll be giving it a try.

[image: Bandcamp embeds screenshot]

EXTRA:

I also found this helpful thread: [Is there anyway to visualize youtube audio from an iframe using the web audio api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535244/is-there-anyway-to-visualize-youtube-audio-from-an-iframe-using-the-web-audio-ap)

However this solves for only YouTube. Other services (and I'm mainly looking at Bandcamp here) don't have an API to stream the audio, so it would have to be from the iframe itself.

Since the audio is playing on the site it seems there ought to be some way to intercept between the media service and the user, but right now I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Maybe, if the different sites provide APIs for such things. The more popular sites sometimes do.

Comment: I think the domains need to be the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe

Comment: Thank you @evolutionxbox ! These led me in a good direction and I updated the post. Found a function when inspecting the embedded element that I may be able to call.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, for security reasons.

Content of different origins will not be accessible.